# Teamcity failing to collect changes from a git repo

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

We have a Teamcity instance running on a Win 8 machine, pulling from a git repo. We've just moved to a new server for git, so the IP has changed. I remoted onto the machine and did a git pull so that the known hosts was updated with the new IP.

I thought that this would resolve the problem, but Teamcity is still failing to collect changes:

```
Started 'Wed Sep 02 17:40:50 BST 2015' on 'attdivdt03' by 'Phil'
Finished 'Wed Sep 02 17:40:51 BST 2015' with status 'FAILURE Unable to collect changes'
TeamCity URL http://177.89.75.282:8080/viewLog.html?buildId=2859&buildTypeId=win8client_BuildTestPackageDebugX86 
TeamCity server version is 9.0.1 (build 32116)

[17:40:50]i: TeamCity server version is 9.0.1 (build 32116)
[17:40:50]E: bt3
[17:40:50] : Checking for changes (started)
[17:40:50] : Collecting changes in 1 VCS root
[17:40:50] :     [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] VCS Root details
[17:40:50] :         [VCS Root details] "GitLab (Win8Client) (1)" {instance id=6, parent internal id=3, parent id=win8client_GitLabAdgAtTUV1_2, description: "git@gitlab.piksel.com:adg-win-8/win-8-client.git#refs/heads/master"}
[17:40:51]E: Failed to collect changes, error: List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
[17:40:51] : Build finished
```

As I'm able to pull changes manually from a command prompt, it suggests that the ssl certificate is fine, there's just something breaking in Teamcity. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

And upgrading from 9.0.1 to 9.1.1 fixed it. Not sure if some bug was fixed or whether the upgrade just gave something the kick it needed.